# Access denied to member of group with full permissions

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions

I was recently appointed to be the admin for my school's publications lab. One of my first duties was to allow several new students access to the `K:\Pub` folder. I added them to the `Publications` group in Active Directory, but that didn't seem to work. Looking at the Security Properties on the `K:\Pub` folder, the `Publications` group has full permissions (except "Special permissions") on that folder.

I'm new to Windows administration (what little admin experience I have is with Linux), so I think I could be missing something rather obvious. Any help for this new admin would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the users logged off of the domain and logged back on since the time you added them to the group? A user's access\security token is generated at logon and changes to this token (group membership changes) only take affect when a new token is generated at logon.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the NTFS permissions, are there any groups that have "Deny" marked and are the new students in them? Deny overrides all NTFS permissions. Another thing to look at would be the permissions on the share if these are being accessed from a network share. Also, if they were added to the AD group after they logged in, they will need to log off and log back on to get the new group membership to be recognized.